# Rolling Resistance of an Deformable Sphere

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

Say that there is some spherical object which is soft enough to deform and flatten out significantly under its own weight when placed on a hard surface (like depicted in the image below)

[image: a black semi spherical object squishing as it rests on the ground]

What would the force required be to roll this kind of object along a flat ideal surface at a certain speed be, and if there even is a way to calculate this required force, would it be reached by software modelling or is there some set of equations that can yield a result?

Comment: To get started: See Johnson's *Contact Mechanics*, Chapter 9, "Rolling contact of inelastic bodies," including the references and the papers citing those references.